# Django user-to-groups in userAdmin, and group-to-users in groupAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to have many-to-many widget in admin-panel in user-tab to pick groups, that user belong to, and similar many-to-many widget in group-tab to pick users, which should belong to that group?

Comment: The default admin form for users should have a many to many for groups already, is that what you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's the easy way and the hard way.

The easy way is to use Django's `InlineModelAdmin` objects. This way, however, you cannot use the group widget.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class UserSetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User.groups.through
    raw_id_fields = ('user',)  # optional, if you have too many users

class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    inlines = [UserSetInline]

# unregister and register again
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, MyGroupAdmin)
```

The hard way requires you to build your own form, manually load and save the related users:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Users',
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
            "users", is_stacked=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = ()  # since Django 1.8 this is needed
        widgets = {
            'permissions': admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                "permissions", is_stacked=False),
        }


class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    form = GroupForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # save first to obtain id
        super(GroupAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.user_set.clear()
        for user in form.cleaned_data['users']:
             obj.user_set.add(user)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.form.base_fields['users'].initial = [o.pk for o in obj.user_set.all()]
        else:
            self.form.base_fields['users'].initial = []
        return GroupForm

# unregister and register again
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, MyGroupAdmin)
```

Comment: You don't know how many times you saved my ass. :) Thanks again.

Comment: There is also a [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2452/) but your "hard way" is really better!

Comment: The "hard way"  is just great !!

For Django >= 1.8 you just need to add  `exclude=()` to `ModelForm:  Meta:` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306288/removedindjango18warning-creating-a-modelform-without-either-the-fields-attri/28306347

Comment: I created a git repository, with 100% test coverage, travis support, and pypi installable: https://github.com/microdisseny/django-groupadmin-users