# RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Django project and when I tried to access 127.0.0.1:8000/articles/create, I got the following error in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
/home/(my name)/django_test/article/forms.py:4: RemovedInDjango18Warning:  Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form ArticleForm needs updating
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

In addition, I also got the following error when visiting my actual localhost site:

```
ValueError at /articles/create/

The view article.views.create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

And here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from article.models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse
from forms import ArticleForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
# Create your views here.

def articles(request):
    language = 'en-us'
    session_language = 'en-us'

    if 'lang' in request.COOKIES:
        language = request.COOKIES['lang']
    if 'lang' in request.session:
        session_language = request.session['lang']

    return render_to_response('articles.html',  
                          {'articles':
                           Article.objects.all(), 'language' : language, 
                           'session_language' : session_language})

def article(request, article_id=1):
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article': 
                                            Article.objects.get(id=article_id) })

def language(request, language='en-us'):
    response = HttpResponse("setting language to %s" % 
                        language)

    response.set_cookie('lang', language)
    response.session['lang'] = language

    return response

def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')

        else:
            form = ArticleForm()

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))

        args['form'] = form 

        return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I looked at the Django documentation but I couldn't find a solution to my problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first message is not an error, it's just a warning. For the second one you'll need to post your view code: as the message says, you're not returning a response object.

Comment: You don't handle GET requests. Your return is inside `if request.POST:`

Comment: I don't understand. I looked at the code my return is inside if request.POST. Could it be an indentation error?

Comment: for **Django 2.0** + it raises an error and project won't run, I got it working by adding `fields='__all__'`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

For your form, it's a warning, not an error, telling you that in django 1.8, you will need to change your form to

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article 
        fields = '__all__' # Or a list of the fields that you want to include in your form
```

Or add an `exclude` to list fields to exclude instead

Which wasn't required up till 1.8

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

As for the error with your views, your return is inside of an `if` statement: `if request.POST:` so when it receives a get request, nothing is returned.

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')

    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form 

    return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)
```

Just dedent the `else` block so that it's applying to the correct `if` statement.

Comment: That problem was fixed so thank you for that but I still have the ValueError at articles/create. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @brown1001 you should include your views.py because there is no way to know what's wrong with it other than that you didn't return a `HttpResponse` object

Comment: I just included views.py in my posting above.

Comment: @Ngenator it worked with a tuple and not a list i.e.  `fields = ('unique_id', 'name'`)

Comment: One of the problems with newbies is the indentation of the lines. Sometimes, a wrong line indentation causes the block to lose its unit and a property becomes disconnected from the block.

Answer (score 10):

You just need...

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ()
```

...to fix your form. You'll need to post your view code to see what's up with that.

Answer (score 6):

if you use `fields = __all__` as Ngenator suggested, and if it's a project that might have to run under various versions of Django, the following conditional will be needed:

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 6):
    fields = '__all__'  # eliminate RemovedInDjango18Warning
```

otherwise you get the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (a, l, _) specified for CrispyTestModel`, as seen here: https://travis-ci.org/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/jobs/56996180

Comment: According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use), you would rather explicitly set all fields that should be edited in the form using the `fields` attribute. Unless there are no security concerns, using  `__all__` is known to be much less secure and has led to serious exploits on major websites (e.g. [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation)).

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you don't return anything if the request is not a POST. You should move everything from the `else` statement onwards back one indent.